# How to validate @RequestMapping requests by condition?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I'm using `hibernate validations` for validating incoming requests in spring `@RestController`.

Problem: I want to reuse the same `DTO` object in multiple endpoints. But validate some fields only by condition (eg only on specific endpoints).

```
@RestController
public class ProductsServlet {
    @GetMapping("/avail/product")
    public Object avail(@Valid ProductDTO product) {
        //should validate id field only
    }       

    @GetMapping("/sell/product")
    public Object sell(@Valid(with = GroupFuture.class) ProductDTO product) {
        //should validate id + from field
    }       
}

public class ProductDTO {
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String id;

    @Future(groups = GroupFuture.class)
    private Date from;
}
```

Of course the `@Valid(with = GroupFuture.class)` statement is invalid. But it shows what I'm trying to achieve.

Is that possible?

Comment: In Spring you should be able to use `org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated` which allows you to specify a group.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Also having to use the `Default.class` group to validate any fields not having a group.

```
@GetMapping("/sell/product")
public Object sell(@Validated({Default.class, GroupFuture.class}) ProductDTO product) {
}
```

Comment: can you able to update your answer with `ProductDTO`?

Comment: There is no modification done to `ProductDTO`. It just works as is.